# MinifiedJS $.request() with Basic Authentication

Tags: javascript, basic-authentication, minifiedjs

I am trying to make a request with Basic Authentication using MinifiedJS.

Here is my current code:

```
$.request("get", requestURL, null, {
            xhr: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            user: "admin",
            pass: "admin"
        })
      .then(function success(result) {
          var response = JSON.parse(result);
          promise.fire(true, response);
      })
      .error(function error(e) {
          console.error(e);
          promise.fire(false, e);
      });
```

The requestURL is valide, so are the credentials. I don't see any credentials sent on the Chrome Developer console. Am I missing something here?